# Change Jupyter R-Kernel engine from 32 bit to 64 bit easily

Tags: r, 32bit-64bit, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I'm using Jupyter with R Kernel to create training forms.
With some packages of R, I need to use a 32 bit release of R engine, and for others (the main part) 64 bit.

So my goal is to be able to switch really easily from a R Kernel 32 bit to a R Kernel 64 bit really easily.

From now on, the only thing I've been able to do is

- getting a 32 bit R Kernel Under Jupyter when I previously installed the Kernel Under a 32bit version of my R engine
- getting a 64 bit R Kernel when previously installed the packages and the R Kernel Under a 64 bit R engine

To install the Kernel, my code is always the same :

```
    install.packages(c('repr', 'IRkernel', 'IRdisplay'),
     repos = c('http://irkernel.github.io/', getOption('repos')))
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to edit your kernel spec file:

- Under windows, got to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\` and copy the  `ir` folder to e.g. `ir64bit`
- edit the `kernel.json` file so that it reads `[...]"argv": ["C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-3.2/bin/x64/R.exe", [...]` -> full path to `R` in the `x64` (or `i386`) subfolder of `bin`.
- change the display name to something you recognise in the UI (e.g. in this case `"R 3.2 64bit"`).
- restart the notebook server

Comment: Excellent !! This is exactly what I needed !