# can I force 64bit version installation of R in windows?

Tags: r

I did quite a bit of Google searches without success. when I [download](https://mirror.rcg.sfu.ca/mirror/CRAN/) and install R in windows 10 64bit I cannot chose 64bit version and the 32bit version is installed. Can I somehow force the installation of the 64bit version of R in Windows? Thanks.

Maybe I talk nonsense and I have the 64 bit version installed? Version gives:

```
platform       i386-w64-mingw32            
arch           i386                        
os             mingw32                     
system         i386, mingw32               
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2021                        
month          11                          
day            01                          
svn rev        81115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
nickname       Bird Hippie
```

The reason I ask is that when I try to use reticulate it complained about it being 32-bit and I can also only use 4BG, which I think is a 32bit thing?

Comment: Are you saying that it does *not* install the 64bit version, or that you want it to avoid installing both versions?

Comment: thanks I added my question. maybe I already have 64 bits?

Comment: That is the 32bit version, but that doesn't mean it is not installed. My guess is that `R.home("bin")` returns something akin to `"c:/R/R-4.0.5/bin/x64"` (installing R within `"c:/Program Files/"` causes some problems since it has a space in the path). Regardless of the presence/absence of `Program Files`, if yours is returning `"c:/R/R-4.0.5/bin/i386"`, does the `".../x64"` path exist?

Comment: thanks R.home("bin") returns C:/R/R-4.1.2/bin/i386" but there is a C:\R\R-4.1.2\bin\x64 folders. can I switch (always!) to x64 especially for notebooks? guess i may also need to reinstall 64bit versions of all packages?

Comment: Now we get to the interesting part: the specific R engine (32 vs 64) is being controlled by the interface, which in this case is a notebook. I don't use notebooks but I believe that you can control the specific engines rather directly. I suggest you [edit] your question to reflect that it is the notebook doing it to you, not the installation, and look for appropriate tags as well, perhaps from [tag:jupyter-notebook] or [tag:rnotebook].

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/36174666/3358272

Comment: The installer should allow you to deselect installation of the 32bit version. I would uninstall R and only install 64bit R. I'm assuming you are not using software that requires a specific or 32bit version.

Comment: @Roland thanks just doing this - never noticed this option ...

Comment: @roland you can post this as answer if you want?